# referring to JSON key with out using specific name

Tags: json, loops, object-literal

lets say I have a JSON/object literal like so:

```
var animals = {
    dogs : {
        breed : 'breed name'
        weight : 'fat'
    },
    cats : {
        breed : 'breed name'
        weight : 'fat'
    }
}
```

because dogs and cats are the same, is there a way to abstract that key?  So for example if you were doing a loop on animals, how would you have a single loop and get to breed and weight of dogs and cats with out actually using dogs and cats?  The JSON I have goes a couple levels deeper than this before this happens.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can loop over the keys of the object.

```
for(var animalName in animals) {
   currentAnimal=animals[animalName];
   console.log(animalName,currentAnimal);
}
```

That will loop through all your animals and print the name and the associated object.

Just FYI: Your JSON is invalid, you need to add commas between the properties